# Referer link block only works for 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I am trying to block a website from linking to my website, but a block only works for about 5 minutes.

I tried both ht access and javascript code.

Is it possible the referer has a code to undo my block? I can't find any information about this.

I used this javascript;

```
<script language="JavaScript"> if ((document.referrer.indexOf("www.tebannensite.nl")
> -1)) { location.href = "http://www.somewhere.nl"; } </script>
```

And this ht access code

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} otherdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: How do you know it works for 5 minutes?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can actually do it this way, because it is up to the browser  to send the referrer. It might be, that some browsers just don't send the referrer, so your block doesn't work

Comment: I know it works for 5 minutes because I tested it.

Comment: Skriptotajs, is there a way to do it that will ignore whatever browser?

Comment: Change it so it only accepts requests from your domain, rather than trying to block other referrers.